# "Template "index.html" not found" при создании сайта с помощью aiohttp

Tags: python, jinja2, aiohttp

Прохожу туториал по aiohttp [здесь](http://demos.aiohttp.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#templates) и не могу решить  проблему с главой Templates. У моего проекта такая структура:

```
app
 |--main.py
 |--views.py
 |--templates
     |--index.html
```

И код выглядит следующим образом:

```
# main.py

aiohttp_jinja2.setup(app, 
        loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates'))
```

```
# views.py

from aiohttp_jinja2 import template

@template('index.html')
async def index(request):
    return {}
```

```
<--index.html-->
<head>
    <title>Text</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>hello world</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```

Но когда запускаю программу и открываю вкладку в браузере, то выдает надпись:

> Template "index.html" not found

Замена пути в FileSystemLoader с относительного на абсолютный не помогает, браузер все равно выдает ту же надпись, причем в консоли ошибок нет. В чем может быть проблема?
Знаю, что во Flask'e, вроде, есть возможность вручную настроить путь до папки templates, есть ли что-то подобное для aiohttp?

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык

Comment: Путь указывается относительно текущего каталога. Если у вас текущий каталог не `app`, то папка `templates` не найдётся